# SQLAlchemy engine.connect() fails for Snowflake using keypair authentication

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My goal is to be able to write a pandas dataframe to Snowflake using the `to_sql()` function. I am able to successfuly query from Snowflake using `read_sql()` with no problems. It appears that to_sql() requires a slightly different configuration I can't figure out. I've tried two different approaches that I've outlined below.

I'm guessing, but could be wrong that the keypair authentication seems to be the problem. When I remove the private key parameter in both approaches, I get an error that the password is missing, rather than the particularly unclear errors I get otherwise. Perhaps not having the password specified is short circuiting the attempt and I really have another problem.

Alternately, if there is a better way to write an entire pandas dataframe to Snowflake I'm happy to entertain other options.

#### <s>Method 1 Snowflake Connector</s>

*edit: it appears that sqllite is the only database supported if the connection isn't a SQLAlchemy connection*.

This approach fails with `DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting`

```
import snowflake

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    account=acct,
    warehouse=wh,
    database=db,
    schema=sc,
    user=usr,
    private_key=pkb,
)

df.to_sql('TABLENAME', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

#### Method 2 - SQLAlchemy Engine

I've found documentation on how to use a private key with SQLAlchemy. However, it fails with `ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL` on the call to `engine.connect()`...

```
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine(URL(
    account=acct,
    warehouse=wh,
    database=db,
    schema=sc,
    user=usr,
    connect_args={
        'private_key': pkb,
    }
))

with engine.connect() as conn:
    df.to_sql('TABLENAME', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

The traceback for both these errors are very long, but I'm happy to post them if it would help troubleshoot.

Comment: You need to pass `connect_args` to `create_engine()`, not to `URL()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with #2 is that you missed a closure. The `connect_args` is part of the `sqlalchemy.crate_engine` call, not the `snowflake.sqlalchemy.URL` one.

Corrected code (as documented at the [snowflake-sqlalchemy GitHub README](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-sqlalchemy)):

```
engine = create_engine(URL(
    account=acct,
    warehouse=wh,
    database=db,
    schema=sc,
    user=usr,
    ),
    connect_args={
        'private_key': pkb,
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Sean for the response. The strange thing is that, although I can connect using the solution provided by Dave Novelli, I get an error why I try your solution. 

```
DatabaseError: (snowflake.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 250001 (08001): Failed to connect to DB: xxx.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
```

Comment: @GeorgePipis perhaps you can open a question with more details, as there is probably some discrepancy in your implementations?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what is wrong with #2, but I found out that combining #1 and #2 will work...

```
import snowflake.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
    account=acct,
    warehouse=wh,
    database=db,
    schema=sc,
    user=usr,
    private_key=pkb,
)

engine = create_engine(f"snowflake://{acct}.snowflakecomputing.com", creator=lambda: conn)

try:
    with engine.connect() as c:
        # Note: the table name MUST be all lowercase for some reason, even though Snowflake uses all caps
        df.to_sql('TABLENAME'.lower(), con=c, if_exists='replace', index=False)
finally:
    engine.dispose()
    conn.close()
```